# System.NullReferenceException in Xamarin.Forms UWP with 2.4.0.280 version when Layout<View> containing Grid added to StackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

In Xamarin.Forms UWP the following code throws System.NullReferenceException with Xamarin.Forms version 2.4.0.280.

```
public class CustomLayoutView : Layout<View>
{
    Grid grid;

    public CustomLayoutView()
    {
        grid = new Grid();
        Children.Add(grid);
    }
    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        grid.Layout(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }
}


<StackLayout>
   <local:CustomLayoutView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The stack trace of the exception is below.

> Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer.GetDesiredSize(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint) 
>       Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.Xamarin.Forms.Internals.IPlatform.GetNativeSize(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement element, double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.GetSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Layout.GetSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint) 
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Measure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint, Xamarin.Forms.MeasureFlags flags)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.CalculateNaiveLayout(Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutInformation layout, Xamarin.Forms.StackOrientation orientation, double x, double y, double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.CalculateLayout(Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutInformation layout, double x, double y, double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint, bool processExpanders)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout.LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Layout.OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize(double width, double height) 
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Bounds.set(Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement child, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle region)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Page.LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Page.UpdateChildrenLayout()
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.SetSize(double width, double height) 
>       Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll!Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Bounds.set(Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle value)
>       Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.UpdatePageSizes()
>       Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP.dll!Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.OnRendererSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs sizeChangedEventArgs)

The exception is not thrown with Xamarin.Forms versions greater than 3.0. But I want to keep using 2.4.0.280. Is there a workaround to avoid this exception without upgrading Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue has been fixed on the new version. But if you don't want to update to the fixed higher version, you can try to change the `StackLayout` to be other [Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts), such as [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.grid?view=xamarin-forms).